# Trying to combine multiple columns with mapply creates enormous list

Tags: r, mapply

I´m kind of a noob when it comes to programming and R so bear with me, if this is a stupid question.

I have a dataframe, in which I want to combine multiple pairs of columns each to a new column with a new name.

For this I have three vectors, two containing the name of each of the columns that I want to combine and one with the names of the new columns

Say we have

```
df <- data.frame("col_a" = c("value", NA , "value", "value"),
"col_b" = c("value", "value", NA, NA),
"col_c" = c(NA, "value", NA, NA),
"col__d" = c(NA, NA, "value", "value"))
```

With the aforementioned vectors then being

```
vec_new <- c("col_e", "col_f")

vec_1 <- c("col_a", "col_b")

vec_2 <- c("col_c", "col_d")
```

I thought about using such a function

```
fun <- function (x, y, z){mutate(df, x = coalesce(y, z))}
```

and then using mapply to use it on my dataframe like so

```
df_new <- mapply(fun, x= vec_new, y= vec_1, z= vec_2)
```

What I expected was for it to basically build a new column called col_e from col_a and col_c and then every other pair in vec_1 and vec_2, which it does, when I do it manually for one pair like this

```
df_new <- mutate(df, col_e = coalesce(col_a, col_c))
```

However, what I get, is a list, which when I convert it to a dataframe

```
df_new_2 <- as.data.frame(df_new)
```

gives me col_e and col_f as columns with the old columns as rows

And if  I use it on my actual dataframe I go from around 800 variables to over 120000.

What`s happening here? Is there something wrong with my mapply approach? Or am I doing a stupid mistake by just throwing as.data.frame on it?

Thank you very much for any tip!

Edit: 
What I expected was something like this

```
df_new <- data.frame("col_e" = c("value", "value", "value", "value"),
"col_f" = c("value", "value", "value", "value"),
"col_a" = c("value", NA , "value", "value"),
"col_b" = c("value", "value", NA, NA),
"col_c" = c(NA, "value", NA, NA),
"col__d" = c(NA, NA, "value", "value"))
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question by adding the head of your expected output data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mapply`

```
df[vec_new] <- mapply(function(x, y) dplyr::coalesce(df[[x]], df[[y]]), vec_1, vec_2)

df
#  col_a col_b col_c col_d col_e col_f
#1 value value  <NA>  <NA> value value
#2  <NA> value value  <NA> value value
#3 value  <NA>  <NA> value value value
#4 value  <NA>  <NA> value value value
```

Comment: That´s exactly what I am looking for unfortunately when using it on my actual data I get  Error: Argument 2 must be a `factor` object, not a character vector

Comment: @Kaiserhamster How are you using it? Because it seems to work on your sample data. What is `vec_1` and `vec_2` in your actual case?

Comment: well, they actually are character vectors, but that is also true for the vectors in the sample data so I do not understand where the difference lies that breaks it.

Comment: Sorry, but it is difficult to guess without a reproducible example.

Comment: I tried running my own sample data including your solution through R and somehow I get another result than here. For col_f I get `"value" "value" NA NA`

Comment: @Kaiserhamster That is because you have a typo in data.frame call, for `col_d`. It is `col__d` in your example. you need to delete 1 `_`.